# Display database table on v-calendar

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi Guys hope someone can help,  I am working on the test project using Laravel for backend and vue, vuetify for the front end.

I have this store table

[image: table]

and I want to display on v-calendar based on the date from the store table

[image]

any idea how to make this work?, maybe you have some reference or link you can share.

[edit]

I got this code from `https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/#usage` but am still lost, hope someone can explain and point out what I should do.

thanks

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      type: 'month',
      types: ['month', 'week', 'day', '4day'],
      mode: 'stack',
      modes: ['stack', 'column'],
      weekday: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      weekdays: [
        { text: 'Sun - Sat', value: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
        { text: 'Mon - Sun', value: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0] },
        { text: 'Mon - Fri', value: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
        { text: 'Mon, Wed, Fri', value: [1, 3, 5] },
      ],
      value: '',
      events: [],
      colors: ['blue', 'indigo', 'deep-purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'orange', 'grey darken-1'],
      names: ['Meeting', 'Holiday', 'PTO', 'Travel', 'Event', 'Birthday', 'Conference', 'Party'],
    }),
    methods: {
      getEvents ({ start, end }) {
        const events = []

        const min = new Date(`${start.date}T00:00:00`)
        const max = new Date(`${end.date}T23:59:59`)
        const days = (max.getTime() - min.getTime()) / 86400000
        const eventCount = this.rnd(days, days + 20)

        for (let i = 0; i < eventCount; i++) {
          const allDay = this.rnd(0, 3) === 0
          const firstTimestamp = this.rnd(min.getTime(), max.getTime())
          const first = new Date(firstTimestamp - (firstTimestamp % 900000))
          const secondTimestamp = this.rnd(2, allDay ? 288 : 8) * 900000
          const second = new Date(first.getTime() + secondTimestamp)

          events.push({
            name: this.names[this.rnd(0, this.names.length - 1)],
            start: first,
            end: second,
            color: this.colors[this.rnd(0, this.colors.length - 1)],
            timed: !allDay,
          })
        }

        this.events = events
      },
      getEventColor (event) {
        return event.color
      },
      rnd (a, b) {
        return Math.floor((b - a + 1) * Math.random()) + a
      },
    },
  }
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <v-sheet
      tile
      height="54"
      class="d-flex"
    >
      <v-btn
        icon
        class="ma-2"
        @click="$refs.calendar.prev()"
      >
        <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-select
        v-model="type"
        :items="types"
        dense
        outlined
        hide-details
        class="ma-2"
        label="type"
      ></v-select>
      <v-select
        v-model="mode"
        :items="modes"
        dense
        outlined
        hide-details
        label="event-overlap-mode"
        class="ma-2"
      ></v-select>
      <v-select
        v-model="weekday"
        :items="weekdays"
        dense
        outlined
        hide-details
        label="weekdays"
        class="ma-2"
      ></v-select>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn
        icon
        class="ma-2"
        @click="$refs.calendar.next()"
      >
        <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-sheet>
    <v-sheet height="600">
      <v-calendar
        ref="calendar"
        v-model="value"
        :weekdays="weekday"
        :type="type"
        :events="events"
        :event-overlap-mode="mode"
        :event-overlap-threshold="30"
        :event-color="getEventColor"
        @change="getEvents"
      ></v-calendar>
    </v-sheet>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to pass data through `events` prop of `v-calendar` 
You can see how to pass data in vuetify docs code. 
They are sharing examples.

One of examples [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/v-calendar/prop-type-category.vue)

Comment: hey man, thanks for the replay I updated my question and added some codes I got from vuetify but am still confused.